# How to Snoop proof your wpf application?

Tags: wpf, security, snoop

Snoop allows you to look inside the application and change element properties.
Its a great asset for developers, but can be a security issue in some cases, like when we have users who like to look in places where they shouldn't be looking. Is there a way to do something to block applications like Snoop from "snooping" your application?

And if there is no way to block it, what do you recommend to do to minimize security risks?

Snoop is a utility that allows you browse visual tree of a wpf application and view and change properties. Its very useful when you are trying to debug something and have no idea what is going on. You can find more [here](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, been wondering the same myself

Comment: Can you give more information on this "Snoop" program, or post a link to information on it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By implementing security properly. If your "security" can be thwarted with a tool like Snoop, then you're doing it wrong.

Suppose there's a command that only certain users can execute. It sounds like the only place you're enforcing this is at the UI level (by disabling the corresponding button, for example). That being the case, you're right - I could easily use Snoop to enable the button and execute the command. But you should be enforcing the security constraints on your server, or perhaps in your command execution logic if you have no server. Basically, security should be implemented as close to the thing you're trying to protect as possible. Security at the UI level is merely for convenience of the user.

Comment: Kent, thank you for your response. I agree with you, security should not be implemented at the UI level. On my project we use commands and we have logic in CanExecute that will disable buttons for certain users (and they can't be reenabled using snoop), as well as server safeguards that prevent users from being able doing certain things. However we have other applications that don't use commands and buttons are just being hidden, so they can be easily "snooped".

Answer (score 47):

There actually is a way to detect whether your application is being "snooped" by the snoop program. The solution I will give is not a silver bullet, and if someone really wants to snoop your application, they'd have to modify the snoop source code (it's an open source project).

What snoop actually does is it injects an assembly into your application, and the injected assembly recursively examines your applications visual tree starting at the root. In other words, snoop actually runs *inside* your application. That being said, the solution is to raise an event when the snoop assembly is injected into your application.

First, you need to subscribe to the assembly-loaded event somewhere in your application (preferably the begginging):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);
```

Then, you would implement the handler somewhat like this:

```
        void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.LoadedAssembly.FullName.StartsWith("ManagedInjector"))
            MessageBox.Show("hey you, stop snooping");//and shut down your application.
    }
```

You would probably need to enhance this solution for real silver-bullet solution, but at least this solution will definitely stop the current latest version of snoop being run as is (without the code modified). The better solution would be to check that no external assemblies are being injected into your application.

However, Kent is still right in the fact that a utility like Snoop should not cause any security vulnerabilities since security should not be implemented at the UI level. But at least this shows you how to prevent people from "snooping" your application.

Comment: This is great. And in combination with Kent's answer exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Great responses for a very good question,

I want to add an example of the password that should never be saved in your datacontext, as snoop check also the datacontext of the UI, so if you use the right control PasswordBox you will find that you can’t bind the password property, that means even if you snoop the application you can’t get the password as it is not saved in any property

But we found many people who try to create a work around (helpers, behaviors, usercontrol ...) to bind the password, but they forget that snoop can get it like that

So your server should never trust your client , every time it should check the right privilege (as we can sniff the client request using Fiddler for exp then rebuild a custome request to by pass client application security)