# MultiDataTrigger with OR instead of AND

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, visibility

I am trying to set multiple `DataTriggers` on my `Button`. I did some research and found that `MultiDataTrigger` allows you to do this. I want the `Visibility` property of my `Button` to be set to false if the `CCTVPath == string.Empty` OR `PermissionsFlag == false`. This is what I have so far;

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" x:Name="cctvFeedButton" Content="Live Feed"
        Width="100" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Click="OnCCTVButtonClick">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CCTVPath}" Value=""/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding PermissionsFlag}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

And in my code-behind I set `PermissionsFlag` like so;

```
public bool PermissionsFlag { get; set; }

private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PermissionsFlag = false;
}
```

As you can see `PermissionsFlag` is definitely false, and the there are definitely empty `CCTVPath` however the `Button` is never hidden. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _permissionsFlag;
    public bool Flag
    {
        get { return _permissionsFlag; }
        set
        {
            _permissionsFlag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PermissionsFlag");
        }
    }

    private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Flag = false;
        CCTVImageCollection = GetImages();
        imageListBox.ItemsSource = CCTVImageCollection;
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

In my XAML:

```
<Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Button">
               <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PermissionsFlag}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
 </Button.Style>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

tranform Conditions into two independent DataTriggers

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CCTVPath}" Value="">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PermissionsFlag}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

make sure that binding paths are correct (check VS Output window for possible exception messages)

---

also: don't rely only on hidden state of Button, implement permissions properly in code (`OnCCTVButtonClick`). read why here:

[How to Snoop proof your wpf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981959/how-to-snoop-proof-your-wpf-application)

---

---

auto-property PermissionsFlag (`public bool PermissionsFlag { get; set; }`) doesn't notify view about changes.

it is possible to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (in my test window it is done like this: `public partial class Window3 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged`) and then raise event when property changes.

here is a complete working example which I used for test

```
public partial class Window3 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        //PermissionsFlag = true;
        CCTVPath = "youtube.com";
    }

    private bool _permissionsFlag = false;
    private string _cctvPath;

    public bool PermissionsFlag
    {
        get { return _permissionsFlag; }
        set
        {
            _permissionsFlag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PermissionsFlag");
        }
    }

    public string CCTVPath
    {
        get { return _cctvPath; }
        set
        {
            _cctvPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CCTVPath");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDemos.Views.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="chkPermissionsFlag" 
                  Content="PermissionsFlag" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=PermissionsFlag, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CCTVPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <Button x:Name="cctvFeedButton" Content="Live Feed"
                    Width="100" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CCTVPath}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PermissionsFlag}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ASh. When I do this, even when `PermissionsFlag == false` the `Button` is still displayed, when I would expect it to be hidden regardless of the value of CCTVPath.

Comment: I expected something was wrong as if I remove the `CCTVPath` `DataTrigger` then again it does not act as I would like to. Can I just add a method in that does this or do I need a whole new class to raise the event? Do you have any good examples at hand?

Comment: In the Page's `OnLoaded` method I use `DataContext = this;`. `PermissionsFlag` is just set within the page using `public bool PermissionsFlag { get; set; }`

Comment: Should `OnPropertyChanged("PermissionsFlag");` be `OnPropertyChanged("_permissionsFlag");` ? Does this also mean I need to change `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PermissionsFlag}" Value="False">`

Comment: Ok and do I use `Flag == false` to set the `_permissionsFlag` to false?

Comment: I've updated my question , can you see anything wrong with that code? (it's still not hiding the `Button`)

Comment: Ok one final question, when should I be calling `PermissionsFlag == false` for it to hide the `Buttons`? Can I do it in the `PageOnLoaded` method? My `Buttons` still aren't hiding!

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks again for your time. I notice now that the event would only be fired when the `CheckBox` is checked, is that correct? that's not what I;m looking to do, I'm looking to set the `PermissionsFlag` in the code-behind based on a `MySQL` query which will then change the `Button` to true or false

Comment: @CBreeze, I added check box only to see current state of PermissionsFlag (via binding). setting `PermissionsFlag` in code shoul work equally well

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution is to use a single DataTrigger with a MultiBinding.  You could make it work by defining a 'special-case' IMultiValueConverter that assumes 2 items in the object array, and returns true if the first item is an empty string OR the second item is false.  However, you probably won't ever use that converter anywhere else in your code.  So if you are willing to do a little more work up front, you could define 3 simple/reusable converters.

1) an [IMultiValueConverter] 'OrConverter,' which would look something like this:

```
public class BooleanOrConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return values.OfType<bool>().Any(b => b);
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

2) An [IValueConverter] 'IsNullOrEmpty' string converter:

```
public class StringIsNullOrEmptyConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

3) And an [IValueConverter] 'NotConverter:'

```
public class BooleanNotConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return !(bool)value;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Then, in your xaml, the DataTrigger would be defined like this:

```
<Button x:Name="cctvFeedButton" Content="Live Feed"
  Width="100" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Value="True">
           <DataTrigger.Binding>
             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrConverter}">
               <Binding Path="PermissionFlag" Converter="{StaticResource NotConverter}"/>
               <Binding Path="CCTVPath" Converter="{StaticResource IsNullOrEmptyConverter}"/>
             </MultiBinding>
           </DataTrigger.Binding>
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I prefer this solution over the use of 2 separate DataTriggers for readability; it better expresses the behavior you are defining - it is 'or' logic: a singular set of 2 conditions that should hide the button.

Answer (score 1):

I used these triggers to make Add button disabled when textboxes are empty:

OR (If **one of** textboxes get filled, the button will enable)

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Usernametxtbox}" Value=""/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Password, ElementName=passtxtbox}" Value=""/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

AND (If **both** textboxes get filled, the button will enable)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Usernametxtbox}" Value="">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password, ElementName=passtxtbox}" Value="">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: it's the other way around