# How to create a logic "OR" behavior in a MultiDataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <!--Here I want to compare with an OR behavior-->
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Username}" Value="" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Username}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No Username"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

For this to be triggered, `Username` has to be `null` and `empty` which make no sense. In fact, **I want an OR behavior with these two values**.

**NOTE**

I know that I could add multiple `<DataTrigger>` (like for example in [MultiDataTrigger with OR instead of AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396419/multidatatrigger-with-or-instead-of-and)) and since they are handled in order it would be fine, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'm looking more for a *one-liner* solution.

Comment: @Clemens The answer of the duplicate is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Does that means it is impossible ?

Comment: Obviously, yes.

Comment: @Clemens Hope it truly is.. The answer is 2 years old.

Comment: _If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question._ What to do if I did initially ?

Comment: It is so happened that I'm the author of duplicate answer, but I have a shorter suggestion for this question, but it was closed before I could post the answer. Voting to reopen

Comment: @ASh That was my guess. But you know we're in 2018 now, I must not be offended by an impulsive closing...

Comment: @ASh Why don't you just edit your existing answer? Or is it a suggestion that doesn't make sense in the context of the other question?

Comment: @Clemens, my suggestion won't work for old question. only for this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in case when DataTrigger should work for some value and for `null`, you can replace `null` for that value, using `TargetNullValue` atrribute of Binding.

`TargetNullValue=''` replaces `null` with an empty string.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Username, TargetNullValue=''}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No Username"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

it is also possible to make a visibility converter specifically for empty/null strings and work without triggers:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" Text="No Username"
           Visibility="{Binding Username, Converter={StaticResource MyStringToVisibiltyConverter}}"/>
```

where Convert method will be smth like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var str = value as string;
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: This is a really good answer and is worth way more attention. No other threads were talking about this specific problem. Really sad that @Clemens closed it since traffic will be significantly reduced. Anyway, thank you a lot for feedback !

Comment: @scharette, glad I was able to help. would you mind if I add a link to former duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396419/multidatatrigger-with-or-instead-of-and to your Question, so they show in Linked section and someone else with a similar issue could find them easier?

Comment: I'd say that would be ideal. Both question are related, but you answer a more specific problem here in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it in your binding

```
private string userName;
public string UserName 
{
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) ? null : userName; }
    set { userName = value; }
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative. Didn't answer my specific purpose though. Thanks! +1